# Synchronously post a message to a worker_thread. Sending thread blocked, worker_thread unblocked

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is there a way to synchronously post a message to another worker_thread?  In this scenario

a) the receiving thread will do async networked operations and should *not* be blocked
b) the sending thread *should* be blocked until it gets a response from the receiver

It must be a synchronous function for compatibility with a third-party library.  But the function's return value is computed from async networked operations which I have moved into another thread.

I plan to use `SharedArrayBuffer` and `Atomics.wait` in the sending thread to wait for a response.  This makes sense because the sender must be blocked.

However, if I use `SharedArrayBuffer` instead of `postMessage` to *send* the message, then the receiving thread must use a `setImmediate` polling loop as opposed to waiting for a `MessagePort` message event.  I'd rather not use `Atomics.wait` in the receiving thread because, ideally, it has an unblocked event loop for ongoing async operations.  I'll use polling or blocking if necessary, but ideally I can find an alternative.

Comment: No.  You can't block the main thread waiting for a response from the worker thread.  The event loop has to be running for you to get a response from the worker thread (because it comes through the event loop).   I would suggest you post the real problem here so we can help you attack the actual problem, not just your attempt at a solution.

Comment: Why not use `postMessage` to send the request and `wait` to accept the response?

Comment: @jfriend00 I *can* block the main thread waiting for a response by using Atomics.wait.  The response is written into a SharedArrayBuffer, then the worker_thread uses Atomics.notify to wake up the main thread.  This question actually pertains to synchronously *sending* the message to the worker thread, not waiting for the response.

Comment: @Bergi `postMessage` does not actually send the message to the worker thread until the sender's event loop has been able to cycle.  I'm hoping there is a synchronous call I can make to manually flush the postMessage queue.

Comment: `postMessage()` goes through the event loop.  I don't know of any way to bypass that.  It's my advice to rethink how you have this designed to use asynchronous notifications, not rely on synchronous logic.

Comment: @jfriend00 The whole point of this endeavour is to interop with a third-party library that requires the function to be synchronous, so my question is not about design advice; it's asking about the limitations of node's APIs.

Comment: There is no "good" way to make an asynchronous operation in node.js be synchronous.  There are blocking hacks that involve `child_process.execSync()` and some things you can do in a native code add-on, but that's about it.  You don't want to seem to want to hear that, but that's the way it is.  If it were me, I'd either find a different 3rd party library that can appropriately interface with an asynchronous operation or I'd modify the existing 3rd party library to do so.

Comment: So, the hack would be the put the asynchronous operation in another node program and synchronously run it as a child and get the result from the child process when it finishes.  If you use any of the `child_process.xxxxSync()` operations, it will block your main app, get you the result and you can then return it to your synchronous function.  This is a giant hack.  If this is a server, it ruins the scalability of your server.

Comment: I figured it out, actually.  I'll answer the question myself.  The question is not about general advice, which I already know.  It's about specifically understanding the behavior of worker_threads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out, what I want to accomplish can be done entirely synchronously, *and* using `postMessage`.

Instead of using the default `MessagePort` created with the worker, I create my own `MessageChannel` and pass one of the ports to the worker when it starts.  This is necessary because we need a reference to the main thread's port later on.

Start the ports manually with `.start()`.

When the worker needs to reply to the main thread, call `.postMessage()` to send the message, then use `Atomics.notify()` to wake up the main thread.  A 4-byte `SharedArrayBuffer` is sufficient, since we are not transferring any data via the `SharedArrayBuffer`; it is only used to wake up the main thread.

In the main thread, use `Atomics.wait()` to wait for notification, then `receiveMessageOnPort` to synchronously pull the message from the port.  (this is why we need a reference to the main thread's port, mentioned above)

Comment: Is there any documentation about this or did you find out by experimentation only?

Comment: Turns out the whole thing can be done synchronously.  When I have time I'll update the answer.  I think you just need to .start() the ports manually.  The docs sorta talk about this, but not explicitly.

Answer (score -1):

I know this is a old post, but I was able to do this with the async/await keywords with the postMessage and onMessage wrapped in a promise.

Here is some example typescript.

```
public async SendSynchronous(name:Message, value: any)
{
    if(GetElapsedTimeInMS != null)
        value.time = GetElapsedTimeInMS();

    value.sendAck = true;

    let messageData: MessageData = {
        message: name,
        value: value
    }
    let sendCommand = async () => 
    {
        return new Promise((resolve,reject) => 
        {
            this.mPort.onmessage = ({data}) => 
            {
                this.mPort.onmessage = (ev) => { this.HandleMessage(ev); } 
                
                 if (!data.value.result.cmdResult) 
                 {
                     reject(data.error);
                 }
                 else 
                 {
                    if(data.value.result.ReturnValue != null) 
                        resolve(data.value.result.ReturnValue);
                    else
                        resolve(true);
                 }
            }

            this.SendAsynchronous(name, value);
        });
    };

    //let t = performance.now();
    //console.log("calling " + name);
    let result: any = await sendCommand();
    //let d = performance.now() - t;

    //console.log("SendSynchronous " + d);
    
    this.mCurrentSyncCount = 0;

    return result;
```

Comment: `async`/`await` is not synchronous though.